# TwitchLib.Client.Services.MessageThrottler usage

Tags: c#, bots, twitch

Just a quick question: How do you use the MessageThrottler method? I’m using it like so:

```
client = new TwitchClient();
client.Initialize(credentials, TwitchInfo.ChannelName);

client.ChatThrottler = new TwitchLib.Client.Services.MessageThrottler(client, 20 / 2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

and the bot does not respond what so ever whenever this is active in the code. Any ideas as to what I’m doing wrong?